# Install dependencies based on condition

Tags: python, bash, continuous-integration, containers, travis-ci

I am using Travis-ci.org as continuous integration server developing some Python packages. I would like to install project dependencies from PyPi server conditionally. Builds from master branch should install dependencies from the real PyPI server while builds from other branches should install dependencies from TestPyPI.

I tried to use TRAVIS_BRANCH environment variable from an external bash script, but with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
  python:
    - "2.7"

install:
    - ~/install_dependencies.sh

script:
    - python runtests.py --with-coverage  --cover-package=package
    - python setup.py test
    - python setup.py sdist --format zip

after_success:
    coveralls
```

**install_dependencies.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "${TRAVIS_BRANCH}" = "master" ]; then
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install cloudshell-automation-api>=7.0.0.0,<7.1.0.0
else
    pip install -r requirements.txt --index-url https://testpypi.python.org/simple
    pip install cloudshell-automation-api>=7.0.0.0,<7.1.0.0 --index-url https://testpypi.python.org/simple
fi

pip install -r test_requirements.txt
pip install coveralls
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not a bash guy, but are you missing a `==` instead of `=` inside your if statement?

Comment: @Oasiscircle me neither. But it seems that both work the same. In my case the problem is with the directory. I'll post an answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the execution of the Bash script from the .travis.yml. 
It needs to be executed like this:

```
bash ./install_dependencies.sh
```

Below file works fine:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
python:
    - "2.7"

install:
    - bash ./install_dependencies.sh

script:
    - python runtests.py --with-coverage  --cover-package=package
    - python setup.py test
    - python setup.py sdist --format zip

after_success:
    coveralls
```